# Entityframework Mapping Issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using entity framework on mvc but I am having a problem with this method. All I am doing is a reflection method below and don't understand why I am getting a field mapping error.

I also get the following error on the fields mentioned here.

Error :-

```
Error   13  Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 205:Each of the following   
columns in table FormBuilder_Form_Fields is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
FormBuilder_Form_Fields.ID is mapped to <FormFieldsForm.Form.ID, FormFieldsForm.FormFields.ID>
 C:\NewDevelopment\CaseddimensionsCMS\CaseddimensionsCMS\CaseddimensionsCms.edmx    206 11  CaseddimensionsCMS

Error   14  Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 228:Each of the following columns in table FormBuilder_field_values is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
FormBuilder_field_values.ID is mapped to <FormFieldValues.FieldValues.ID, FormFieldValues.Form.ID>
```

I am not to sure what this means as quite new to entity framework.

I have included a screen shot of the edmx file in the layout designer:

[image: pic]

This is  a pastbin of my edmx file

http://pastebin.com/GeL6mZd4

As to long a code didnt want to be posting it here.

Comment: How was the image put in the post so I no for future as I have a rep below ten

Answer (score 8):

Having the same issue I found the solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx).
In short, you should:

> Fixing this duplicate mapping issue requires a referential constraint,
>   which the designer will only support in the next release, so save the
>   edmx file, close it, then right-click it in Solution Explorer, select
>   “Open With…” and double click on “XML Editor”.
>
> In the CSDL section, you will see the ProductProductImages
>   association:

Update your associations like:

```
<Association Name="FormsFormsFields">
  <End Type="TableSplittingModel.Forms" Role="Form" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Type="TableSplittingModel.FormFields" Role="FormFields" Multiplicity="1" />
</Association>
```

by adding a ReferentialConstraint

```
<Association Name="FormsFormFields">
  <End Type="TableSplittingModel.Forms" Role="Forms" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Type="TableSplittingModel.FormFields" Role="FormFields" Multiplicity="1" />
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="Forms"><PropertyRef Name="id"/></Principal>
    <Dependent Role="FormFields"><PropertyRef Name="id"/></Dependent>
  </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Comment: Fixed the same thing in VS2012 by right-clicking on the association, "Show in Model Browser", then in the properties adding a new ReferentialConstraint from the properties window.